# Get specific key from an array

Tags: arrays, symfony, session, twig

Here is what I put in my Symfony session

```php
$this->session->set('teams', [
  'team_1' => ['MyTeamNameA' => ['player-1' => $safe['team-1-player-1'], 'player-2' => $safe['team-1-player-2'], 'player-3' => $safe['team-1-player-3'], 'player-4' => $safe['team-1-player-4'], 'points' => 0]],
  'team_2' => ['MyTeamNameB' => ['player-1' => $safe['team-2-player-1'], 'player-2' => $safe['team-2-player-2'], 'player-3' => $safe['team-2-player-3'], 'player-4' => $safe['team-2-player-4'], 'points' => 0]],               
]);
```

And now, in my Twig, I want to retrieve my `team_1`'s name, for example, I did this:

```
app.session.get('teams')['team_1']
```

It doesn't work, but, if I do a dump of this last piece of code, I get this result pictured below:
[image: My dump() result in my page]

I feel that i'm close to the answer, and yet so far.

Comment: Here's a hint: The team name is that array [`key`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/keys.html). You should consider passing a proper object directly to twig instead of implementing that logic in the view.

Comment: I tried with just the |key , the only way i found to get what i wanted is this :

{{ app.session.get('teams')['team_1']|keys|join }}

Comment: That's because `keys` returns an array itself, even if there's only one element.

Comment: i don't like the way i did with the |keys|join , but seem to be the only way?

Comment: You should restructure your data instead of trying to "hack" it, e.g. `[ 'teams' => [ 'name' => 'TeamNameA', 'players' => [ 'Foo', 'Bar', ], ], ];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`keys`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/keys.html) will return you a simple array, then the keys are integer from `0` to the `(array | length) - 1`, to express it in Twig.

Note that this is actually the same behaviour as PHP, when you define an array like

```php
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

that would be strictly equivalent to

```php
[0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar', 2 => 'baz']
```

So in your case, since you only have one element in the array you can use `array[0]` or `array.0`.

All together, this would work:

```
{{ (app.session.get('teams').team_1 | keys).0 }}
```

<sup>*Could be tested from https://twigfiddle.com/b6iy8i*</sup>